# Enviar url desde un enlace a whatsapp

Tags: html, whatsapp

Tengo un problema que no he podido solucionarlo.
Estoy intentando enviar una url desde una web a un número de whatsapp.
Esta es la url que estoy enviando
https://wa.me/000000000?text=https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393
pero al momento de ingresar a la ventana de enviar el mensaje la URL me muestra incompleta como se indica en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he estado revisando y llegué a la conclusión de que el carácter "&" (amperstand) corta todo el texto que está a la derecha de este.

Cómo podría solucionar este problema.
Lo he enviado mediante **&** pero tampoco funciona.

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: y cual es tu codigo que falla? te fijaste en la doc de la libreria?

Comment: Debería codificar los caracteres especiales de la URL. Desde PHP puedes utilizar la función `urlencode()`

Comment: Falta ver tu código. Tal como está tu pregunta es muy amplia y no se puede reproducir el problema. Te invito a leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Agradezco a todos sus comentarios, en sí era una pregunta abierta y se trataba más de un tema de codificación de la url que estaba enviando, lo he logrado solucionar y adjuntare la respuesta en esta pregunta por si alguien lo requiere en un futuro.

Answer (score 1):

Una revisado a detalle las preguntas frecuentes proporcionadas en el sitio oficial de whatsapp, lo adjunto a continuación.
https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat/?lang=en

En este menciona claramente que la url debe tener una codificación en específico, para lo cual utilicé una herramienta de codificación y de esta manera codificar la url.
El carácter "&" es reservado por lo que si se envía este directamente reacciona de la manera que me presentaba el problema.
Para enviar una url mediante un enlace whatsapp es necesario pasar el String generado por un codificador, lo adjunto a continuación el que yo utilicé, pero puede usarse cualquier otro.

https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Pero para resumir toda esta respuesta si llegan a tener el mismo problema simplemente necesitan cambiar el carácter "**&**" por **%26**.